# Simplifying P(x|y,z) to P(x|z)

Tags: probability, bayesian, games

I am looking for the probability of an outcome (x in Win, y in Opponent Actions and z in Opponent Cards) in a poker scenario.

I need a mathematical proof to simplify  $\Pr (x \mid y, z)$ to $\Pr (x \mid z)$

Comment: I made a mistake sorry, i need to proof that P(x|y,z) = P(x|z)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The identity $\Pr(x \mid y,z) = \Pr(x \mid z)$ does **not** hold in general.

It holds iff and only if $X$ is [*conditionally independent*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence) of $Y$ given $Z$.